# The value of QR Code Scanner cannot show on new activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, qr-code

I am trying to make a simple QR Code scanner and run well if the result shows in the MainActivity. But when I'm trying to generate new Activity as a result, it can't show. Would you like to help me with this problem? Thank you.

Here is the result of the scanner code in the scanner.java:

```
@Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class));
        ResultActivity.scanText2.setText(rawResult.getText());
        onBackPressed(); 

    }
```

And here is the code of my new Activity for showing the result:

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static TextView scanText2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_patient);

        scanText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanText2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with this:

1. You are launching `PatientActivity`, not `ResultActivity` in `handleResult()`
2. You are trying to set the value of a `TextView` in another `Activity` with this code:
   `ResultActivity.scanText2.setText(rawResult.getText());`

This is an absolute no-no. Pass the data to `ResultActivity` as an `Intent` extra when you launch it. You cannot access the views of another `Activity` like that.

3. You expect that `ResultActivity.scanText2` will contain a reference to a `TextView`, but at this point it will only contain `null`. The reason is that it takes some time for `ResultActivity` to actually start and call its `onCreate()`. You have not accounted for this timing in your code. To solve this problem, just see (2) above.

Also, you should have gotten a bunch of crashes with useful messages in your logcat. In the future please look there to solve problems and/or post the messages with stacktrace in your Stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your command. After fixing many code. Now it works.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Glad you were able to fix the problem. If my answer was helpful, you can "accept" it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. This gives me some reputation points, increases your "accept ratio" and will help other developers that may have a similar problem.